# AngularJS: date filter with ISO 8601 dates

Tags: angularjs

I notice from the Angular docs that the date filter should work fine with ISO 8601 dates in the format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

But when I try filtering a date in this format, I don't see any difference in the output. Here is a fiddle to demonstrate what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/4zpqj7zb/

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Some Date: {{ someDate | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy' }}
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.someDate = "2015-04-30T11:17:983.008Z";
});
</script
```

Why am I not getting the properly formatted date in my expression?

Have I missed something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string date is wrong in seconds. You have `sss.sss` (983.008) while it should be `ss.sss` with value <= 60 (58.008), here is a correct one:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/echyxt3t/1/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


Some Date: {{ someDate | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy' }}

</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.someDate = "2015-04-30T11:17:58.008Z";
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ah right ok, well the date string I am getting back is from a server side team I am not part of. Does this mean they are not using ISO 8601 formatted dates? If so, any idea what format that is I am getting back?

Comment: This means they are sending you a wrong string for the date, I mean they are generating that "by hand" probably because it's not a different format it's really wrong. (I'd contact them to explain this)